# How to stop printing a space in python2 print with a comma

Tags: python

I am trying this `for` loop that prints some output. **I am using python `2.7.5`**

And after every output, there is an **extra space printing** when I use the `,` after `print()` method. How can I stop this?

```
def printHeader(self, header1, header2):
        # for header1
        first = "|   |      "+constants.ICON_BOX
        header1_count = len(header1)

        available_space_for_first_part = 53 - (len(first) + header1_count)
        print(available_space_for_first_part)

        for i in range(available_space_for_first_part):

            print("."),
```

The output for this will look like:

```
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

There are additional spaces, how can I get rid of them?

Output I want:

```
..............................
```

Comment: This doesn't work in `python 2.7.5` that is why I specifically mentioned the python version

Comment: The top answer to the linked question describes a way to do this that works in Python pre-2.6 (using `sys.stdout`).

Comment: If I had to guess, the downvotes are because this is a very easy question to search for. If you put your exact title that you've written into Google, many existing answers come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do

```
s = ""
for i in range(available_space_for_first_part):
  s += "."
print s
```

Comment: OP is using python 2.7, `print` is a statement and not a function in 2.7

Comment: Yes, please provide a solution for python version 2.7.5

Comment: i've corrected my code. now it works

Comment: @IainShelvington `print("abc")` is valid in Python 2.7 - only the `end=""` keyword parameter isn't.

Comment: thank you this approach is better

Comment: @ThierryLathuille oh yeah you're rigth both ``print s`` print s and ``print(s)``  is possible in 2.7

Comment: Although the latter will also print `()` in the output.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I can't see how that would happen in 2.7 - Was it so with older versions where  `print(1, 2)` would have been interpreted as 'print the tuple'? I don't have anything around to test it...

Comment: @ThierryLathuilleIn In 2.7, `print (1, 2)` prints `(1, 2)`. The `()` cause it to be interpreted as a tuple, and is printed literally just like how `print [1, 2]` prints `[1, 2]`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate actually i thought you where right but i've tested it with python 2.7.3 and it doesn't print the brackets. weird ...

Comment: @manzet I just tested it. Are you sure you're not on 3? Unless `.3` "fixes" this. I'm not sure what sub-version I'm on.

Comment: I'm on `2.7.17`. I'll check the release notes for `.3`.